Is there a way to add a timeout to a Locust task?
For context, I have a Locust task that issues an HTTP request that I want to time out if it doesn't complete in N seconds.  This differs from using the request timeout parameter since that only fails if no bytes are returned within a timeout.
I used the following User:
class MyLoadTestUser(FastHttpUser):
  network_timeout = 8.5
  connection_timeout = 2.0
  
  @locust.task
  def t(self):
      start_time = datetime.now()
      resp = self.client.post(url={path}, json={body}, timeout=9.5)
      end_time = datetime.now()
      print((end_time - start_time).total_seconds() * 1000)

The printed latency was sometimes over 15-20s so it seems like neither FastHttpUser's network_timeout nor the client's timeout is being obeyed.
